# How to protect 1 column in table from updation/deletion?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How to protect 1 column in table from **updation/deletion**?

The user has access to the database but need to protect 1 column of specific table from updating.

Rather than giving read only access, will a **trigger** work in this case?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Depending on the DBMS you can simply revoke the update privilege on that column.

Comment: sorry.. plz consider Oracle DB..

Comment: You can use a before Update trigger for that, and raise an error whenever we try to update the column.

Answer (score 4):

You can't revoke the update privilege for a single column, but you can define the columns that can be updated:

Assuming your table has three columns: `column_1, column_2, column_3` and you want to prohibit `some_user` from updating `column_3` you can do the following:

```
grant select,insert on some_table to some_user;
grant update (column_1, column_2) on some_table to some_user;
```

The user can see all the data, insert new rows (include data for `column_3`) but `some_user` can never change anything in `column_3`.